# jQuery sort html table having different type columns such as text, number and date:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html table and jQuery function. I want to sort the table when user clicks on table headers. This works fine if the table column is text or number. But not working properly when the column is date type.

To sort the date column, what I was thinking of is to put the condition like this:

```
 if(index === 3){//for date column sort...

 } else {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    } 
 }
```

But couldn't really figure out how to sort the table when I have the date range in Date column. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
//sort table
$('th').click(function(){
 //alert($(this).index())
 $('th').css({'background-color' : '#cccccc'});
 $(this).css('background-color', '#808080');
 var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
 var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
 this.asc = !this.asc
 if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
  var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
  return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
 
  }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }
```

```css
th{
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>S.No.</th>
   <th>Number</th>
   <th>Text</th>
   <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>Canada</td>
   <td>01/06/2016 - 01/07/2018</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3000</td>
   <td>USA</td>
   <td>12/08/2017 - 12/12/2017</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>1202</td>
   <td>Mexico</td>
   <td>12/09/2018 - 01/07/2018</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>20</td>
   <td>Brazil</td>
   <td>04/29/2018 - 05/01/2018</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>1680</td>
   <td>Germany</td>
   <td>04/29/2018 - 05/01/2018</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to split the date and get the first part only from the date range. 
For eg: you have date like: `12/09/2018 - 01/07/2018`, so what I would do is just get the first part of it `(12/09/2018)`, get the time from that date,  use it to compare with another date and sort:

```js
//sort table
$('th').click(function(){
 //alert($(this).index())
 $('th').css({'background-color' : '#cccccc'});
 $(this).css('background-color', '#808080');
 var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
 var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
 this.asc = !this.asc
 if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
  if(index === 3){//for date column sort...
   return function(a, b) {
   var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
   var datePartsA = valA.split(" - ")[0].split("/"); //MM/DD/YYYY 
   var dateA = new Date(datePartsA[2], (datePartsA[0] - 1), datePartsA[1]); 
   var dateResultA = dateA.getTime ();
   
   var datePartsB = valB.split(" - ")[0].split("/");
   var dateB = new Date(datePartsB[2], (datePartsB[0] - 1), datePartsB[1]);
   var dateResultB = dateB.getTime ();
   
   return $.isNumeric(dateResultA) && $.isNumeric(dateResultB) ? dateResultA - dateResultB : dateResultA.localeCompare(dateResultB)
   }
  } else { //for other sort 
   return function(a, b) {
   var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
   return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
  } 
  } 
}

function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }
```

```css
th{
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>S.No.</th>
   <th>Number</th>
   <th>Text</th>
   <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>Canada</td>
   <td>01/06/2016 - 01/07/2018</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3000</td>
   <td>USA</td>
   <td>12/08/2017 - 12/12/2017</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>1202</td>
   <td>Mexico</td>
   <td>12/09/2018 - 01/07/2018</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>20</td>
   <td>Brazil</td>
   <td>04/29/2018 - 05/01/2018</td>
   
  </tr><tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>1680</td>
   <td>Germany</td>
   <td>04/29/2018 - 05/01/2018</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

If both date have first part same, you can compare the second part too.